# Javascript for validating if uploaded file is image isn't working

Tags: javascript, python, django, web-development-server

I'm doing some web development using Django. There comes a part where user could upload images to my server.

Here is the Javascript side of the code.

```
var uploadField = document.getElementById("file_upload"); 

uploadField.onchange = function(){
    var file_type=this.file[0]['type']; // file_type = 'image/jpg'
    if (file_type.split('/')[0] !== 'image'){
        alert("Not an Image");
        this.value = "";
    }
    else if(this.files[0].size > 2097152){
        alert("File is too big!");
        this.value = "";
    }
    else{
        this.form.submit();
        document.getElementById('celimsg').innerHTML='Analyzing image...';
        document.getElementById('celi').src=gif_url;
    }
}
```

It didn't work. When the files are uploaded, nothing happens. But if I remove the validation part:

```
var uploadField = document.getElementById("file_upload");

uploadField.onchange = function(){
    if(this.files[0].size > 2097152){
        alert("File is too big!");
        this.value = "";
    }
    else{
        this.form.submit();
        document.getElementById('celimsg').innerHTML='Analyzing image...';
        document.getElementById('celi').src=gif_url;
    }
}
```

It started working again.

Unlike other web development platform, Django doesn't support debugging for javascript and I can't put print statements on it etiher.

Comment: Use `console.log` to see the value of the `file_type` in your browser console.

Comment: @5Volts Couldn't you run it in Chrome or another browser and use the developer tools?

Comment: Insert a `debugger;` statment where you want your browser's debugger to stop execution and exit to the dev tools.

Comment: I've added a console.log(file_type); and see Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.uploadField.onchange (one_button.js:5). Looking into it now

Comment: add `console.log(this.file)` or `console.log(this.file[0])` etc. until you find something interesting (or insert a `debugger;` statement and look at all the variables interactively in the debugger..)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I spelled 'files' incorrectly.

```
var uploadField = document.getElementById("file_upload");

uploadField.onchange = function(){
    var file_type=this.files[0]['type'];

    if (file_type.split('/')[0] !== 'image'){
        alert("Not an Image");
        this.value = "";
    }
    else if(this.files[0].size > 2097152){
        alert("File is too big! Keep it under 2MB.");
        this.value = "";
    }
    else{
        this.form.submit();
        document.getElementById('celimsg').innerHTML='Analyzing image...';
        document.getElementById('celi').src=gif_url;
    }
}
```

Cheers!